# Computer recognizes monitor only after I replug it

Tags: windows-7, display, intel-graphics

I got a Lenovo E73 with an onboard Intel HD 4400 graphics, which has a VGA and a DisplayPort. VGA works without any problem. But the DisplayPort only works after I re-plug the monitor when Windows is started. Monitor works fine on other PCs and I got the same problem with different monitors.

Monitor says no signal when starting the PC and after I re-plug it the display works as intended. Drivers are up to date. Using Windows 7.

Would be great if someone can help me.

Comment: The computer is set to defaultly output to onboard monitor whe starting. Try to find a setting for this in BIOS

Comment: i can switch between onboard and pci-e but both ports are onboard. its the same onboard card.

Comment: I know, I was talking about default output: onboard monitor or external monitor connected to onboard Display Port.

Comment: the only option i found is the one above: Select primary video device that will be used for graphic output. PCI-e Graphics Device, Internal Graphics Device

Comment: Have you tried changing this option?

Comment: Yes selected internal graphics. And in the sub menu. "Enable multimonitor": same as before. Even flashed the newest bios

Comment: And what abou the second one (PCI-e graphics device)?

Comment: Same result. And i tested it with some other Lenovo E73,same result. But i dont habe the Problem with another M93 which has an Intel 4600

Comment: Sorry I don't know any other thing that you might do.